# laravel 9 error 404 page not found when update

Tags: php, laravel

At the most basic understanding, I've been trying to match the route and the form action. I think that I am doing it right but I wonder why the error keeps on showing. I may have missed something anywhere but I just really couldn't find it. Please help. With a very tight schedule, I need to complete this project.

When I submit the form it goes to this address.

index.blade.php

```
<tbody>
@foreach($payments as $payment)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->first_last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->business_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->business_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->phone_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->postal_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $payment->order->address }}</td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-action="{{ route('payments.send', $payment->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#send" data-id="{{ $payment->id }}">اSend</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            @php $status = $payment->status @endphp
            <span class="{{ $status['bs_class'] }}">
                    {{ $status['label'] }}
                </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $payment->accounting_code   }}</td>
    </tr>
    @include('Admin.layouts.modal')
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

js

```
<script>
    $('#send').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var action = button.data('action');
        var orderId = button.data('id');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('form').attr('action', action);
        document.getElementById("orderId").value = orderId;
    });
</script>
```

modal.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="send" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="send" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <form action="{{ route('payments.accounting', $payment->id) }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <input type="hidden" id="orderId" value="">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="sendTitle">send</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="accounting_code" class="form-label">کد accounting_code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accounting_code" name="accounting_code">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

web.php

```
  Route::put('/payments/accounting/{payment}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PaymentController::class,'accounting'])->name('payments.accounting');
```

PaymentController.php

```
public function accounting(Payment $payment, Request $request)
{
    dd('hello');
    $data = [
        'accounting_code' => $request->post('accounting_code')
    ];
    $payment->update($data);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Did you check whether the request is sent to the URL it should be sent to, with the method that should be used?

Comment: I get `dd` in my controller, but  it did not see dd

Comment: If you run `php artisan r:l --name=payments.accounting` do you get something?

Comment: I see this message. `PUT admin/payments/{payment}/accounting....................................................payments.accounting › Admin\PaymentController@accounting`

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Does your browser's network console indicate that the request was sent to the given URL with the given method?

Comment: I did not see any error in console . network

Comment: I haven't asked about any error, I asked about the request itself

Comment: You are passing the parameter in the wrong way in the action of your form first of all, instead of `{{ route('payments.accounting', $payment->id) }}` it should be `{{ route('payments.accounting', ['payment' => $payment->id]) }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your js code `modal.find('form').attr('action', action)` replaced the form action when showing the modal. Try to change the `data-action` from route `payments.send` to `payments.accounting` for the send button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-action="{{ route('payments.accounting', $payment->id) }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#send" data-id="{{ $payment->id }}">اSend</button>
```